# Load failed for null with size [0x0] class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, android-glide, appglidemodule

I'm trying to load a photo I saved on firebase, It's saved successful but it can't get the image loaded again the error is

"Load failed for null with size [0x0]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model"

I use the simple line on my code

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    currentUser?.let{user ->
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(user.photoUrl)

            .into(image_view)
```

My implementations on Build.Gradle

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

Applied plugin on Gradle.Build

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Thank you for the future answers!

BTW here's my entire code for the fragment

class NotificationsFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var notificationsViewModel: NotificationsViewModel
private lateinit var imageUri: Uri
private val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 100
private val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
private val user = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()



override fun onCreateView(

    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?):
        View? {
    notificationsViewModel =
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NotificationsViewModel::class.java)
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications,container,false)



}




override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)



    currentUser?.let{user ->
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(user.photoUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profilepicture_box_orange_24dp)
            .into(image_view)






    }




    image_view.setOnClickListener {
        takePictureIntent()

    }
    button_save.setOnClickListener{

    }


}

private fun takePictureIntent() {
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { pictureIntent ->
        pictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity?.packageManager!!)?.also {
            startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        }

    }


}


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        val imageBitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap

        uploadImageAndSaveUri(imageBitmap)
    }
}

private fun uploadImageAndSaveUri(bitmap: Bitmap) {

    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val baos1 = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()


        .reference

        .child("pics/${FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid}")
        .child("uid" + ".JPEG")
        .child("uid" + ".PNG")
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos1)
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
    val image = baos.toByteArray()
    val image1 = baos1.toByteArray()

    val upload = storageRef.putBytes(image)
    val upload1 = storageRef.putBytes(image1)

    upload.addOnCompleteListener { uploadTask ->
        if (uploadTask.isSuccessful){
            storageRef.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener{urlTask ->
                urlTask.result?.let{
                    imageUri = it
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

                }

            }

        }

    }

    upload1.addOnCompleteListener { uploadTask1 ->
        if (uploadTask1.isSuccessful){
            storageRef.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener{urlTask ->
                urlTask.result?.let{
                    imageUri = it




                }

            }
        }

    }






    progressbar_pic.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    upload.addOnCompleteListener { uploadTask ->
        progressbar_pic.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        if (uploadTask.isSuccessful) {
            storageRef.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener { urlTask ->
                urlTask.result?.let {
                    imageUri = it
                    imageUri.toString()
                    image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap)


                }
            }
        } else {
            uploadTask.exception?.let {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

    }

}
```

}

I fixed it, I had to add a few more codes and edit some too, this was the fix so it would save the URL and the photo.

```
private  fun uploadImagetoFirebaseStorage(){
    if (selectedPhotoUri == null) return
    val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$filename")

    ref.putFile(selectedPhotoUri!!)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d("dsa","$it")
            ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                it.toString()

                saveUsertoFirebaseDatabase(it.toString())
            }
        }

}

private fun saveUsertoFirebaseDatabase(profileImageUrl: String){
    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid")
    val user = User(uid,username_edittext_register.text.toString(),profileImageUrl)

    ref.setValue(user)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d("","Saved!!!!!!")
        }


}
```

}

class User(val uid: String, val username: String, val profileImageUrl: String)

then I just used Glide module as you usually use it

```
currentUser?.let{user ->

        Glide.with(this)

            .load(user.photoUrl)

            .into(image_view)


    }
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `user.photoUrl` and `image_view` before Glide tries to load them and checking their values in the log?

Comment: Tried it, still just says the same thing

Comment: It's just supposed to print the values to the log. What are the values printed for both of those?

Comment: It it the Log d. code? In the Logcat it shows '2020-03-16 14:19:29.777 7042-7042/com.example.opinionator W/Glide: Load failed for null with size [100x50]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model'

Comment: I meant adding something like `Log.d("My_Log_Tag, "photoUrl: " + user.photoUrl + " imgView: " + image_view)` right before your Glide's load and checking for this text in the Log.

Comment: Fixed it, I had to add and edit a few lines of code, I made sure it was saving in a folder in storage and a few more in database

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have entered the same name in firebase database, e.g- I am trying to send image in my app, in my model I have declared a string 'imageUrl', but in firebase storage I gave the name 'image', make sure that the both names are same.... it will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Most common problem is located in:

```java
Glide.with(this)
     .load(user.photoUrl)
     .into(image_view)
```

`user.photoUrl` or `image_view` is empty. Check with `println()`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view is not set to `View.GONE` which is the reason why Glide sees it as 0x0.