# Glide is not showing images

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-glide

This one works in activity.this one load the image from firebase to recyclerview:

```
            Glide.with(PURPLE_MARKET.this).load(productsModel.getImage()).
                    placeholder(R.drawable.loading).into(holder.producticon);
```

And in a fragment datas are loading perfectly from firebase to recyclerview:

```
            holder.titletv.setText(productsModel.getProductName());
            holder.pricetv.setText("Rs." + productsModel.getPrice() + ".00");
```

The problem starts with loading images to the fragment from firebase,here is the code:

```
            Glide.with(getActivity())
                    .load(productsModel.getImage())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                    .into(holder.imageFav);
```

if you need more updates,please tell me in the comment,
Please give me a solution,i am stucking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Glide.with(getActivity().getContext())`.

Comment: Sorry, android studio is not get getActivity().getContext.it gets getActivity().getApplicationContext().

Comment: @Ashrik Ahamed So does `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` work? If not, what error you get?

Comment: when its time to load the image by glide, the logcat says "Load failed for null with size [0x0] class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model".  please suggest me a solution, i am stucking here.

Comment: @Ashrik Ahamed According to the error, the image uri/url you passed seems to be null, see this post: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/476

Comment: But it loads in an activity

Comment: @Ashrik Ahamed Try using `requireContext()` instead of `getActivity()`.

Comment: Why its not working on this fragment..it says recieved null model...but in activity, not showing that null model error..its perfectly loads to activity...

Comment: @Ashrik Ahamed You can ask this author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684890/load-failed-for-null-with-size-0x0-class-com-bumptech-glide-load-engine-glidee